# How can I route network calls from the cloud via an on-prem Squid proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, ip-address, squid

I have a service running in Azure which involves scraping external websites, however these external sites blacklist non-residential IPs.

I have bought a Raspberry Pi and have installed Squid (running on Ubuntu) on it to act as a transparent proxy, but I'm not sure how I can get my Azure service to use this local proxy server. Is this even possible?

My service currently uses a pay-as-you-go rotating residential proxy, however this is expensive, hence why I'm keen to set the proxy server(s) up manually.

Other solutions to this problem are welcome!